# How to disable Vaadin loading line (top of the page)

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Standard Vaadin Valo theme, I guess.

Sometimes, when the application is processing information and/or loading new pages, a blue line on the very top of the page appears. Must be about 4px wide. If the loading takes way too long, the line increases in width, and even starts glowing (blue to white and forth).

This load indicator is distracting to the users, and thus unwanted.

How do I completely visually disable this load indicator? I'd take any solution there is - even a CSS hack (if applicable) will do.

Comment: https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/9403425  but in fact this blue line/indicator also teels the user that he can't interact with the website at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution would be to change the timings for loading indicator, as this can be done in Java. The delay is set in milliseconds, if you make the first delay 3000 like below it will not show the loading indicator until 3 seconds has passed.

```
UI.getCurrent().getLoadingIndicatorConfiguration().setFirstDelay(3000);
UI.getCurrent().getLoadingIndicatorConfiguration().setSecondDelay(4000);
UI.getCurrent().getLoadingIndicatorConfiguration().setThirdDelay(100000);
```

You only need to do this once for each UI.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following css:

```
  .v-loading-indicator {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
```

If you are using an SCSS theme (you mentioned Valo), you can put it in your VAADIN/themes/mytheme/mytheme.scss file as part of your theme's mixin:

```
@mixin mytheme {
  @include valo;

  // Insert here
  .v-loading-indicator {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```