# Grid taking an abnormal amount of time to become visible

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-grid

We have a `Grid` with 50 to 66 columns.  For some reason, when I call `grid.setVisible(true)`, it takes a little bit to show the grid and refresh things.  In fact, my boss noticed it because there is literally a 5+ second wait for even the blue line at top, let alone the full display of the `Grid`.  The less columns we have, the quicker it is.  As a comparison, I have another `Grid` with 23 columns that is instantaneous, so quick we don't even see the blue line at the top.  Same with a `Grid` of 33 columns.  So my question is this: how can I improve the performance of `grid.setVisible(true)`?  Even showing the blue line at top sooner, as early as possible, would help some.

Displaying the blue line sooner would help, but ideally we would make the user experience better, somehow improve the performance.  So any ideas would be appreciated.

One idea for showing blue line quicker can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43004279/3329922), and I will definitely try it.  But ultimately I think it would be better to improve the performance, thus my question.

NOTE: I know this is entirely at frontend (Vaadin code) because it even happens when I am testing in Eclipse, which is not talking to the DB or web services at all, and is just loading fake static data from an XML file.  Also, it is not getting new data or loading new data into the `Grid`, it is just calling `grid.setVisible(true)`.

NOTE: blue line at top is the normal Vaadin 7 loading data line, and is NOT custom code at all.  I don't even know how to control that blue line, it is totally automatic from my perspective.  It normally displays when the server is sending information to the browser, as far as I can see.

On old Vaadin Forum, we also have [this](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/18497063/grid-slow-when-set-visible-to-true).  I totally forgot about it.  Their, @Olli Tietäväinen says to not do "setVisible", but to use CSS.  Maybe someone else has a better idea, though.

Answer (score 4):

In Vaadin 7 and Vaadin 8 by default Grid is automatically calculating column widths by using headers and snapshot of the first visible rows of data. This is O(n * m) process, where n is amount of columns and m number of visible rows. As column count increases, the process takes increasingly more time. The best way to make Grid rendering faster when you have lot of columns is to use predefined column widths using `Grid.Column#setWidth(double)`.

The automatic column width calculation will skip columns that have predefined width, thus making process considerably faster. Also, verify that you are using Vaadin 7.7.17, as there was performance improving patch included in the latest versions. See comparison table below.

[image]

If you want to hide Grid using css, just do this to toggle a classname

```
grid.addStyleName("grid-hidden");
```

remove

```
grid.removeStyleName("grid-hidden");
```

And add the following in your theme scss file.

```
.grid-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: CSS trick hides the grid, but not the v-slot it is in.  So we have a rule for `.v-grid-hideGrid` and `.v-slot-hideGrid` with `display: none;`, but the `v-slot-hideGrid` is overwritten by an earlier CSS rule that uses `display: block;`.  Finally fixed it with `.v-grid-hideGrid, .v-slot-hideGrid {
   display: none !important;
  }`.  Now the problem is that the form I am "showing" does not expand because "setVisible" logic must take care of "expand" logic (we use `setExpandRatio`).  Any ideas?

Comment: I haven't tried anything like this with Vaadin 7 in ages so can't remember for sure, but have you tried `markAsDirty()` or `markAsDirtyRecursive()` for the layout? Or, to make things simpler for the layout logic, instead of hiding the Grid and the slot, simply removing and re-adding the Grid when needed, which should trigger all necessary logic by default.

Comment: Grid#setVisible(boolean) does markAsDirtyRecursive internally. But if your layout has Grid expanded and other complexities, full rerender may be needed and quick method of hiding Grid with css will not be applicable here, as you probably need the Grid to have fixed height for it to work nicely.

Comment: Yep, makes sense.  Second question:  As per your initial idea (setting column widths, also suggested in the original Vaadin Forum post I linked), can we accomplish the same thing with `column.setMaximumWidth` that we would accomplish with `column.setWidth`, or are the `setMaximumWidth` and `setMinimumWidth` methods too dynamic to improve the rendering speed?

Comment: Related question: Do we have to set the width (or max width or whatever) for all columns or can we get away with not setting the width for a few columns?

Comment: Not setting the widths for some columns is probably ok. It's just that the more dynamically sized columns there are, the longer it takes to calculate the width for each.